# I want to get the inverse of an array while the user input the value

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, reverse

I create a program that get the input of array element size of 10. Everything getting will with the sum of even and odd number. but when it comes to the inverse it didn't work.

i created two arrays where the first getting the value from the user and second copying the element starting from end of the first array..

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (){

  int array[10] , i , odd =0 , even =0;
  int array1[10],b;

    for (i=0 ; i < 10 ; i ++){
        printf("Insert number %d: ",i);
        scanf("%d",&array[i]);
    }

    for (i=0; i < 10 ; i++){
        if ( array[i] % 2 == 0){
            even = even + array[i];
        }


        else

            odd = odd + array[i];

    }


printf("\n The Sum of Even Numbers in this Array = %d ", even);
 printf("\n The Sum of Odd Numbers in this Array = %d ", odd);

 for ( i = 10 , b =0; i>0; i-- , b++)
   {
       array1[b] = array[i];
   }


   printf("\nReverse Order:\n");
   for ( b = 0 ; b< 10;b++ )
   {
       printf(" %d",array[b]);
   }



    return 0;

           }
```

The input will be: `2 3 5 4 6 12 3 7 4 9`

What I expect the out put for the reverse is: `9 4 7 3 12 6 4 5 3 2`

But it gave me same value as : `2 3 5 4 6 12 3 7 4 9` .

Any Idea for how doing this reverse.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the answer by [@Yunnosch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7733418/yunnosch) that identifies the problems in your current implementation, you can refactor (rearrange) your code to sum `even` and `odd` and reverse `array` into `array1` in a single loop. The only other loop you need is the loop to iterate over `array1` outputting the reversed array.

With a bit of re-arranging, you could do something similar to:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

    int array[] = { 2, 3, 5, 4, 6, 12, 3, 7, 4, 9 },    /* array */
        array1[sizeof array/sizeof *array],             /* array1 */
        even = 0, odd = 0;                              /* even/odd */
    size_t n = sizeof array/sizeof *array;              /* no. elem in array */

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {    /* loop over each element in array */
        array1[i] = array[n - i - 1];   /* reverse into array1 */
        if (array[i] & 1)               /* check if odd (bit-0 == 1) */
            odd += array[i];            /* add value to odd */
        else    /* even */
            even += array[i];           /* add value to even */
    }

    /* output results */
    printf ("even sum: %d\nodd sum : %d\n\nreversed: ", even, odd);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf (" %d", array1[i]);
    putchar ('\n');
}
```

(**note:** you can either use `if (array[i] % 2)` or `if (array[i] & 1)` to test whether the element is odd or even. Anding with `1` simply checks whether bit-0 is `1`, if it is, it's an odd number. Modern compilers will optimize to remove the division inherent to *modulo*, so whichever you prefer should pose no penalty)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/revarr
even sum: 28
odd sum : 27

reversed:  9 4 7 3 12 6 4 5 3 2
```

Look things over and let me know if you have questions.

Comment: I see, so if I follow, `if (array[i] % 2)` provides (`-1, 0, 1`) and we don't have to be concerned with `+/-` only `on/off`? (the `on/off` the same as being provided by `array[i] & 1`, but `%` making the goal more apparent?)

Comment: Ah, yes, that was the point looking me in the face but overlooked.

Answer (score 1):

You are outputting the array which you never tried to inverse.

```
printf(" %d",array[b]);
```

should be

```
printf(" %d",array1[b]);
```

Aside, the input by David C. Rankin:
Also `for ( i = 10` ... and `array1[b] = array[i];` assigns from beyond the end of array. It should e.g. better be

```
for ( i = 10 , b =0; i>0; i-- , b++)
{
    array1[b] = array[i-1];
}
```

Comment: Also `for ( i = 10...` and `array1[b] = array[i];` assigns from beyond the end of `array`.

Comment: Thanks, I  added that @DavidC.Rankin